# Trouble playing WAV on ESP32 using I2S with internal DAC

Tags: audio, esp32

I'm trying to use I2S and internal DAC to play WAV files from SPIFF on a Heltec WiFi LoRa 32 V2, using the Arduino IDE.

I have an audio amp and an oscilloscope hooked up to DAC2 (pin 25) of the board and I'm not getting any signal. I've simplified the problem by generating a sine wave (as in the ESP-IDF examples). Here's the code:

```
#include <Streaming.h>
#include <driver/i2s.h>
#include "freertos/queue.h"

#define SAMPLE_RATE     (22050)
#define SAMPLE_SIZE     4000
#define PI              (3.14159265)
#define I2S_BCK_IO      (GPIO_NUM_26)
#define I2S_WS_IO       (GPIO_NUM_25)
#define I2S_DO_IO       (GPIO_NUM_22)
#define I2S_DI_IO       (-1)


size_t i2s_bytes_write = 0;
static const int i2s_num = 0;

int sample_data[SAMPLE_SIZE];

i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
    .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX | I2S_MODE_DAC_BUILT_IN),                                  // Only TX
    .sample_rate = SAMPLE_RATE,
    .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,                           //2-channels
    .communication_format = (i2s_comm_format_t)I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S,
    .intr_alloc_flags = 0,//ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1   
    .dma_buf_count = 8,
    .dma_buf_len = 64,
    .use_apll = false                           //Interrupt level 1
};

i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
    .bck_io_num = I2S_BCK_IO,
    .ws_io_num = I2S_WS_IO,
    .data_out_num = I2S_DO_IO,
    .data_in_num = I2S_DI_IO                                               //Not used
};

static void setup_sine_wave()
{
    unsigned int i;
    int sample_val;
    double sin_float;
    size_t i2s_bytes_write = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < SAMPLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        sin_float = sin(i * PI / 180.0);
        sin_float *= 127;
        sample_val = (uint8_t)sin_float;
        sample_data[i] = sample_val;
        Serial << sample_data[i] << ",";
        delay(1);
    }
    Serial << endl << "Sine wave generation complete" << endl;
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(26, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    //i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, NULL);
    i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
    i2s_set_dac_mode(I2S_DAC_CHANNEL_RIGHT_EN);
    i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_0, 22050); //set sample rates
    setup_sine_wave();
    i2s_set_clk(I2S_NUM_0, SAMPLE_RATE, I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT, I2S_CHANNEL_MONO);
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, &sample_data, SAMPLE_SIZE, &i2s_bytes_write, 500);
    i2s_driver_uninstall(I2S_NUM_0); //stop & destroy i2s driver
}

void loop() 
{
    i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, &sample_data, SAMPLE_SIZE, &i2s_bytes_write, 500);
    delay(100);
    i2s_driver_uninstall(I2S_NUM_0);
    delay(10);
}
```

The code uploads and runs OK but I still get no signal on pin 25. I also looked on pin 26 (DAC1) but that seems to be used by LoRa_IRQ. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, take a look at how you've set up your pins

```
#define I2S_BCK_IO      (GPIO_NUM_26)
#define I2S_WS_IO       (GPIO_NUM_25)
#define I2S_DO_IO       (GPIO_NUM_22)
#define I2S_DI_IO       (-1)
```

According to this specification, pin 26 will output a clock signal, pin 25 will output the line selector (left or right), and pin 22 will output the serial data corresponding to the audio you're sending to your DAC.

```
.sample_rate = SAMPLE_RATE,
.bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
```

Now you've set up your sample rate to 22050Hz, and your bit depth to 16 bits. So on pin 26 and 22 you should be getting a periodic signal of 22kHz, and a periodic signal of 22kHz/16 on pin 25.

Now to your problem. First, the ESP32 board has two 8-bit internal DACs, and they'll output an analog signal with a 8-bit depth. So in reality, pin 22 should be outputting an analog signal. Let's take a look at your code:

```
i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
```

The I2s specification is a 3-line bus specification for audio communication. Since you're using the internal DAC, you don't need these three lines and setting their pins will make the driver assume you want to use them (meaning the DAC pin won't be activated).

```
//i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, NULL);
```

Uncomment this and the driver will assume you want to use the internal DAC.

```
.bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
```

Again, since the internal DAC only takes 8 bits per sample, the driver only takes the 8 most significant bits. You can set this to 8 bits and avoid any problems.

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(26, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    //i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, NULL);
    i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
    i2s_set_dac_mode(I2S_DAC_CHANNEL_RIGHT_EN);
    i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_0, 22050); //set sample rates
    setup_sine_wave();
    i2s_set_clk(I2S_NUM_0, SAMPLE_RATE, I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT, I2S_CHANNEL_MONO);
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, &sample_data, SAMPLE_SIZE, &i2s_bytes_write, 500);
    i2s_driver_uninstall(I2S_NUM_0); //stop & destroy i2s driver
}
```

In your setup function you're installing the I2s driver, then setting the pins for an I2s communication with an external DAC, setting the sample rate to 22050, resetting them to 22050 again, writing 1 cycle of your sine wave, then uninstalling the driver. After you uninstall the driver, it is useless to output anything. Here's a more appropriate approach:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, NULL);
    i2s_set_dac_mode(I2S_DAC_CHANNEL_BOTH_EN); // You also might be sending data to the wrong channel, so use both.
    setup_sine_wave();
}
```

Now the loop function:

```
void loop() 
{
    i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, &sample_data, SAMPLE_SIZE, &i2s_bytes_write, 500);
    delay(100);
    i2s_driver_uninstall(I2S_NUM_0);
    delay(10);
}
```

You don't need to install and uninstall the I2s driver, nor delay the outer function, since the write function writes to a buffer that is consumed in the specified sample rate.

```
void loop() 
{
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, &sample_data, SAMPLE_SIZE, &i2s_bytes_write, 500);
}
```

This is all you need, theorically. But there's a major problem. You defined your audio buffer as an int-array (a list of 32 bit signed values). Then you defined the size of this buffer as 4000

```
#define SAMPLE_SIZE     4000
```

In your write function, the buffer size parameter expects the size in bytes of your buffer, kinda like when you use the malloc function. Since each sample in your buffer has 4 bytes, you're only giving 1/4 of your buffer to the write function. In the end, you're not outputting a sine wave, but a 1/4 of a sine wave.

```
void loop() 
{
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, &sample_data, SAMPLE_SIZE * sizeof(int), &i2s_bytes_write, 500);
}
```

Should do the trick.
I haven't tested this code, but hopefully my explanation will give you some directions as to debug your code.

[I2s driver documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/peripherals/i2s.html) has some code samples that you can check aswell.

Comment: What a thorough answer! Thank you.